# drawLayer: inContext on UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm having trouble drawing a UILabel from a storyboard; it's always blank.  The label is defined as a property, self.rainbowCircle.  Here is the setup in my view controller:

```
self.rainbowCircle.layer.name = @"Rainbow Layer";
self.rainbowCircle.layer.delegate = self;
[self.rainbowCircle.layer setNeedsDisplay];
```

and here is drawLayer: inContext:

```
- (void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    if ([layer.name isEqualToString:@"Rainbow Layer"]) {
        NSLog(@"here");
        NSArray *rainbowColorsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                       (id)[UIColor colorWithHue:0.0                 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
                                       (id)[UIColor colorWithHue:1.0*360.0/6.0/360.0 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
                                       (id)[UIColor colorWithHue:2.0*360.0/6.0/360.0 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
                                       (id)[UIColor colorWithHue:3.0*360.0/6.0/360.0 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
                                       (id)[UIColor colorWithHue:4.0*360.0/6.0/360.0 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
                                       (id)[UIColor colorWithHue:5.0*360.0/6.0/360.0 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
                                       (id)[UIColor colorWithHue:1.0                 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
                                       nil];
        CGColorSpaceRef deviceRGB = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGGradientRef gradient    = CGGradientCreateWithColors(deviceRGB, (__bridge CFArrayRef) (rainbowColorsArray), NULL);
        CGContextDrawRadialGradient(ctx, gradient, self.rainbowCircle.center, 0.0, self.rainbowCircle.center, self.rainbowCircle.bounds.size.width/2.0, kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(deviceRGB);
        CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    } else {
        [self drawPalette:self.currentPalette inLayer:layer inContext:ctx];
    }
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

I've been staring at this for quite some time and just don't see what I'm missing.  The NSLog does show.  Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Is this `rainbowCircle` layer a sublayer of your view?

Comment: Now, rainbowCircle is a UILabel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the delegate of an UIView's layer, it has to be the view itself

Comment: If that were true, then why does drawLayer: inContext exist?

Comment: @MichaelMangold If you create a layer yourself (`CALayer *myLayer = [CALayer layer]`), you are allowed to set its `delegate` to whatever object you want.  If you ask a view for its layer (`self.rainbowCircle.layer`), you are not allowed to modify its `delegate`.

Comment: @MichaelMangold See [the documentation of the `UIView layer` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW31): “Additionally, you should never change the delegate of this layer object.”

Comment: Well that's a big lesson I hope to never forget.  Thank you Sven and rob.